# I want all inventories fifo method to be displayed in column unit sold google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can only one have it show one inventory fifo method column unit sold in sheet FIFO, but I want to show all values sale in column unit sold. Please help me.
I use formula :=IF(A2=$L$1,MIN(C2,$N$1-SUMIF($A$1:A1,$L$1,$F$1:F1)),0)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dCiS5bsZMVWZ1kndoLarSyakm4kEvzt3nnwgcnJrBps/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You will have to use an array to get more than one single value.

For your use case building an array is pretty easy:

```
{A2=$L$1:$L$3} -> {TRUE, FALSE, FALSE}
```

**Note**: In Google Sheet operations between Booleans and Numbers are allowed and Booleans will assume these values: TRUE=1, FALSE=0.

You can use the `SUMPRODUCT` formula to build a simple *Array-Check* and get the corresponding unit sale value in this way:

```
SUMPRODUCT({A2=$L$1:$L$3},$N$1:$N$3) -> 1*2000 + 0*500 + 0*400 = 2000
```

In this way you can get rid of the `IF` statement and only compute the minimum using your own logic:

```
=MIN(C2,SUMPRODUCT({A2=$L$1:$L$3},$N$1:$N$3)-SUMIF($A$1:A1,$L$1,$F$1:F1))
```

The formula is ready to be dragged down and compute all the values that match with your *Array-Check*

### References

[Using Arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

[SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for helping me.But I used the formula and I got a problem is to editing the formula so it will match with the product ID 13595 13596 every time***(SUMIF($A$1:A1,$L$1 or $L$2 or $L$3 ***I have to fix it right here,$F$1:F1)).Do you have a way for them to match them selves?

Comment: If Pruduct id is not sort, can I use the formula?

Comment: It looks like you did not drag down Alessandro's formula (or COPY & PASTE) from F2 all the way down in column F  The formula in F10 has an IF(A10=$L$1...  Since the product ID in A10, 13595, does not match what you have up in L1, the formula returns 0 as you have specified.

Comment: Alessandro, doesn't your formula only function for product IDs in Col A that match $O$1?  I'm not clear what exact result is expected in column F - units remaining in stock (units purchased - units sold) on that date?  If so, is table O1:Q3 the total sales to date, by product, that we use for this calculation?

Comment: I could understand the issue you had with your formula but I cannot understand what you are trying to achieve. I based my answer on the formula you tried to use in your sheet. You didn't include a description of what you need to find nor of your formula. In these cases, it's best to include the expected output with a brief description in your question. Please update your question.